# How to send serial number of pass to device

Tags: ios6, passbook

Now I am in the step when device generate GET request to `webServiceURL/version/devices/deviceLibraryIdentifier/registrations/passTypeIdentifier?passesUpdatedSince=tag`

How the server send the serial of pass and also send last updated/tag; so I need to convert timestamp to string as lastUpdated is string? This is error from console:
`Apr  5 13:45:24 CamMobs-iPod4 passd[21] <Warning>: Get serial #s task (for device b6511c0dd47d04da449ce427b27fea74, pass type pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest, last updated (null); with web service url http://192.168.1.202:8888/passesWebserver/) encountered error: Server response was malformed (Missing response data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query your database and identify the serials (if any) that match `deviceLibraryIdentifier` and `passTypeIdentifier` and have changed since the `passesUpdatedSince` tag.  Hold these in an array.

Then send that array back to the device, or send a 204 response if there are no serials that need updating.

```
$serialsArray = array("abc123", "dec456"); // this array should be populated by your database.

if (!empty($serials)) {
    echo json_encode(array('lastUpdated' => (string)time(), 
                           'serialNumbers' => $serialsArray));    
} else {
   // No serials need updating so send a 204 response
}
```

Comment: lastUpdated is in header ?

Comment: $serials are from database ?

Comment: what about serialNumbers ?

Comment: So $serialsArray is for serials that I select from database ?

Comment: $serialsArray should only contain passes which have changed since the passesUpdatedSince tag (in your current case there should be none).  You query needs to select all serial numbers matching the deviceLibrary and passTypeIdentifier and where the last time they were changed is > than the passesUpdatedSince tag.  You know when you are updating the pass, so whenever you decide to change the .pkpass bundle, you should be storing the lastUpdated tag in the database so that you can respond to this call.

Comment: I not really understand. Thanks anyway !

Comment: If I have updated a pass and make a new updated .pkpass, so what steps do I have to follow next ?

Comment: First, you will need to configure your web service to respond to the "Get Latest Version of a Pass Method".  Then you can start working on sending the push message.

Comment: so I can serial of pass to device by using this :     'echo json_encode(array('lastUpdated' => (string)time(), 
                           'serialNumbers' => $serialsArray));'?

Comment: Now getting latest version of a pass works fine, but I still have error for getting serial of pass. This is the error: [26-Apr-2013 08:16:48 Europe/Berlin] Passbook Error Log: [2013-04-26 13:16:15 +0700] Get serial #s task (for device 0c9454578d100070a87ecc84a8ceb7c6, pass type pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest, last updated 1366955477; with web service url http://192.168.1.202:8888/passesWebserver/webService/) encountered error: Unexpected response code 401

Comment: '401' is an authorization status code. Check you code, as to why you are sending that header, also check your server, if you navigate to that URL in the browser and are prompted for a username/password this would indicate that your server or .htaccess file is restricting access to that path.

Comment: now there 's no error ,but it only responds with 304 and no response for 204 !

Comment: Apr 26 14:21:39 CamMobs-iPod4 passd[8409] <Warning>: Get pass task (pass type pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest, serial number 0001, if-modified-since Fri, 26 Apr 2013 07:20:08 GMT+07:00; with web service url http://192.168.1.202:8888/passesWebserver/webService/) got response with code 304

Comment: I use this code: $query = mysql_query("select serialNo from registration where deviceID = '$deviceID' and passTypeID = '$passTypeID'");
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
   $serialsArray = array($row['serialNo']); 
   
   if(!empty($serialsArray)){
    $querySelect = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(updateTag) AS updateTag from digiCardPass where passTypeID = '$passTypeID' "); 
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($querySelect);
    $updateTag = strtotime($row['updateTag']);

Comment: $tag = "";
  
    if(!empty($_GET['passesUpadatedSince'])){
     $tag = $_GET['passesUpadatedSince'];
     error_log('Tag: ' .$tag,0);
    }
    if ($updateTag > $tag) {

        echo json_encode(array('lastUpdated' => (string)time(), 
                           'serialNumbers' => $serialsArray)); 
              response(200);
             }
            
      }else {
       response(204);
   }

Comment: You shouldn't be sending a 304 at all for this method. It's either 200 with serials or 204 with no serials. The issue lies somewhere in you code. It may help if you step back from your screen an try and map out on paper the path these requests are taking through your code. Sounds like these queries are taking a path trhough your program that they should not be. To find this type of error is going to require you to logically and systematically examine what is happening to reach the point that your code responds with a 304.

Comment: now when I update pass with pushnotification, getting serial method is called, but there're some errors : \

Comment: [02-May-2013 09:01:13 Europe/Berlin] Passbook Error Log: [2013-05-02 14:01:11 +0700] Get serial #s task (for device 2f62ea72ab19e127226ae283efafb903, pass type pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest, last updated 1367474388; with web service url http://192.168.1.202/passesWebserver/webService/) encountered error: Server response was malformed (Array for key serialNumbers in response dictionary must contain objects of type NSString. Found object of type NSNull.)

Comment: Log your response to your error log.  Looks like your query is retuning zero items which if true then you should send a `204` but instead you are appear to be sending an empty array of serials which is why the device is complaining about receiving a null value.

Comment: yes ! now I get another error : [02-May-2013 10:11:03 Europe/Berlin] Passbook Error Log: [2013-05-02 15:11:02 +0700] Get serial #s task (for device 0efc44cb7a0b71e593efe78ba60177e1, pass type pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest, last updated 1367480960; with web service url http://192.168.1.202/passesWebserver/webService/) encountered error: Server response was malformed (Missing response data)

Comment: I response like this  :  if (!empty($serialsArray)) {
      echo json_encode(array('lastUpdated' => (string)time(), 
                           'serialNumbers' => $serialsArray)); 
     }else {
      response(204);
  }

Comment: Thank you for everything !!

Comment: Now I test with more devices, so I have 2 different pass, but I get only 1 serial. This is it: May  2 16:04:54 CamMobs-iPod4 passd[15510] <Warning>: Get serial numbers task completed with update tag 1367485496, serial numbers (
     1
 )

Comment: in database, there are 2 updated pass with different serial, but same content ! so my getting latest version of pass method is not yet right !

Comment: See my answer to your other question - send two requests through the same socket.  Each will should have a unique device token.

Comment: and also getting serial method too !

Comment: I can send serial now : May  3 13:41:03 CamMobs-iPod4 passd[16756] <Warning>: Get serial numbers task completed with update tag 1367563263, serial numbers (
     2,
     7
 )

Comment: but I still get this error : [03-May-2013 08:41:26 Europe/Berlin] Passbook Error Log: [2013-05-03 13:41:26 +0700] Get pass task (pass type pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest, serial number 7, if-modified-since (null); with web service url http://192.168.1.202/passesWebserver/webService/) encountered error: Requested serial number 7, received serial number 2

Comment: I may check getting latest version of pass then !

Comment: Yes your `Getting Latest Version of a Pass` is incorrect - this method passes in the `serialNumber`, but for some reason your code is ignoring it an sending back a pass with the wrong serial.

Comment: I use this code for getting serial: $query1 = mysql_query("select serialNo from registration");
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($query1);
 $serialsArray = Array($row['serialNo']); 
   
   $query1 = mysql_query("select MAX(updateTag) as updateTag from digiCardPass");
   $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1);
   $updateTag = $row1['updateTag'];
   
  if (!empty($serialsArray)) {
       echo json_encode(array('lastUpdated' => (string)time(), 
                           'serialNumbers' => $serialsArray)); 
     }else {
      response(204);
  }

Comment: but it sends only 1 serial !

Comment: I don't know the structure of your database, but your MAX criteria is always only going to return one row (the maximum updateTag).  You'll probably need a join where you are selecting all serials which match the deviceID and have an updateTag greater than the `passesUpdatedSince` tag that the device sends you in the call.

Comment: If I don't select MAX(...) and I just use : if (!empty($serialsArray)) {

       echo json_encode(array('lastUpdated' => (string)time(), 
                           'serialNumbers' => $serialsArray)); 
     } I also cannot get all serial in array !

Comment: I'm not an MySQL expert so will get a better response by posting a MySQL question.  In your question, show your table column names; give an extract from each table's contents; show your query in full; say what you expect to receive back and then say what you are actually getting back.  No need to tag the question as passbook, because it is not passbook related, it is specific to MySQL and your code.